# Optimizing and Parallel Computing for Large Dyadic Intervals

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, parallelization, random, compile

I need help with the efficiency of my code i.e. less time so I can compute for large range of values.

My function `n[x]` takes in a number x and outputs the difference between t and w. The idea behind this code: t = residue class of prime numbers modulo 4, and w = residue class of prime numbers below 3. `n[x]` calculates the difference between t and w for prime numbers below x and returns the difference.

```
n = Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
  Module[{w = 0, t = 0, p = 3},
   While[p <= x, {
     If[Mod[p, 4] == 1, w += 1, t += 1];
     p = NextPrime[p]}
    ];
   Return[Round[t - w]]
   ], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

`n[x]` is my base code. I use it to create my function `ncom[a,b]`. The idea behind `ncom[a,b]`: outputs the maximum and minimum differences of n[x] for values between [a,b].

```
ncom = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{x = a, n0 = n[x], out = {}, cmax = n0, cmin = n0, p},
   While[x < b,
    {p = NextPrime[x];
     n0 = n0 - Mod[p, 4, -2];
     If[n0 > cmax, cmax = n0];
     If[n0 < cmin, cmin = n0];
     AppendTo[out, {p, n0}];
     x = p}]; Return[cmin, cmax]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

My goal is to create a table with five columns: a | b| b/a | Max[a,b] | Min[a,b], where the values of a and b are increasing by dyadic intervals. I generate the values for a and b using `rand[x,y]`, where Min[a] = a & Max[a] = b.

```
rand[x_, y_] := 
 Do[For[k = {}; j = x, j < y, j++, 
   a = {RandomInteger[{3 2^j, 3 2^(j + 1)}], 
     RandomInteger[{3 2^j, 3 2^(j + 1)}]}; 
   AppendTo[k, {Min[a], Max[a]}]]; Return[k], 1]
```

My desired range of [a,b] (with greatest interval in powers of 10^12) occurs when I use `rand[30,50]`. However when I plug the a and b numbers I get from `rand[x,y]` into `ncom[a,b]`, ncom fails to output because its too slow.

So far, I have tried to use floating numbers (which actually ended up insignificant to my code) and `Compile` (including many of its options such as parallelization).   Any other ways of improving the efficiency, aside from those mentioned above, would be of great help. Ideally, my goal is to use `ncom` for numbers up to 10^15.

Comment: AppendTo is very slow. Try out=Join[out,{{p,n0}}]

Comment: Just did that. Improved my code slightly